# R - Rename all column titles right of matching string in column title

Tags: r, tidyverse, rename

I have imported an XLSX files where each column title originally is formatted like "[idNo] nameNo". When I import the xlsx using read_excel, each column name is now:

```
"[id1]\nname1"    "[id2]\nname2"     "[id3]\nname3" ......... "[idn]\nnamen
```

How can I rename all the columns by looking right of the '\n' and retain the 'nameNo' only:

```
"name1"    "name2"    "name3" ....... "namen"
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `sub` to strip off the unwanted content, for a base R option:

```
names(df) <- sub("^.*\n", "", names(df))
```

Using the `dplyr` library:

```
df <- df %>% rename_with(~sub(".*\n", "", .))
```

Comment: Thank you very much! (missing closing bracket in first line)

Answer (score 0):

You can remove everything until `'\n'`

```
names(df) <- sub('.*\n', '', names(df))
```

In `dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>% rename_with(~sub('.*\n', '', .))
```